# how can i verify data is streaming from a rails 3 template handler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've [forked csv_builder](https://github.com/fawce/csv_builder) to support a @streaming parameter. When streaming, the template handler uses a block like this:
 
`Enumerator.new do |output| 
   output.write("writing some data")
end`

I've verified that templates render properly, in terms of the content being correct, but I want to verify that data is streamed, rather than returned in one shot. One idea I had was to generate an enormous file inside a template. When I did this in an rspec test, it indeed takes a few minutes, but it passes when the template returns data in one shot.

Comment: I switched over to use unicorn instead of WEBrick, since unicorn has a configurable timeout for requests and also supports streaming. I was able to make a test application that I can verify with chrome's dev tools. But I still am not sure how to wrap that test in a unit test, since unicorn (afaik) isn't running when I run 'rake spec'.